# How to save a JavaScript object as a hash record

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to save a hidden text field, which is a dynamically-created JavaScript object, as a hash record in the database. The problem is that the record is being saved with empty hash value. Here is the relevant code and errors from the trails I've made:

form code:

```
<%= form_for(@bill, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="hidden">
    <%= f.text_field :items %>
    <%= f.text_field :total_amount %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

JavaScript code:

```
// bill_items is the dynamically created object
var items = JSON.stringify(bill_items);
$('#bill_items').val(items); // Setting Input text value
$('#bill_total_amount').val(bill_total_amount);
$('form#new_bill').submit();
```

The params that are being passed:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "bill"=>{"items"=>"{\"bill_item_1\":{\"product\":\"vaseline 300 ml\",
  \"unit_price\":\"215\",\"quantity\":\"1\",\"discount\":\"0.0\",
  \"amount\":\"215\"}}", "total_amount"=>"215", "transaction_type"=>"Cash", "transaction_id"=>"some_id"}}
```

Controller code:

```
def create
  @bill = Bill.new(bill_params)
  if @rec_saved = @bill.save
    respond_to do |f|
      f.js
    end
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

  def bill_params
    params.require(:bill).permit(:total_amount,
      :transaction_type, :transaction_id, :items => {})
  end
```

model code:

```
class Bill < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :items, Hash
end
```

Using the debugger in the controller near `bill_params` method gives:

```
Unpermitted parameter: items
Return value is: nil
```

When creating a record from the console, it is working fine.

I searched and tried some suggestions but none of them worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of database?

Comment: @DanFarrell  am using postgresql

Comment: Will you ever have a need to search or modify the contents of those records? If so, don't save them as JSON, create a sub-table for those fields and store the information there. It's easy to parse JSON to an object and store it, or to take the records, recreate the object and then serialize it back to JSON.

Comment: Awesome.  Postgres will allow you to store JSON directly, and query it. Any reason to bring a Ruby hash into this between form and database?

Comment: @theTinMan the records are not to be modified but should be searchable. Thought of storing them as a hash and search them using the hash attributes. Any ideas why my code is not working?

Comment: @DanFarrell Tried using JSON directly., but I got `Return value is: nil` from the `params.require` method

Comment: Try doing `permit(:items, :total_amount, :transaction_type)`? The json is probably not recognized as a hash.

Comment: @HoMan that still gives the same error `Unpermitted parameter: items`

Comment: Yes, Postgres allows storing JSON and querying it, but there's an added burden in doing so. For search speed and flexibility it'd be best to store the content of the JSON as separate fields. If the JSON doesn't need to be indexed or individual fields searched or modified, in other words it's static, then leaving it as a string is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that `items` param has a string value, and you are permitting a hash.

First, if there are multiple objects in items, make it an array:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "bill"=>{"items"=>"[{\"product\":\"name\",\"unit_price\":10},{\"product\":\"name2\",\"unit_price\":100}]", "total_amount"=>"215", "transaction_type"=>"Cash", "transaction_id"=>"some_id"}}
```

so that you can permit the keys of objects in the array:

```
private

def bill_params
  params[:bill][:items] = JSON.parse(params[:bill][:items])
  params.require(:bill).permit(
   :total_amount, :transaction_type, :transaction_id, items: [:product, :unit_price]
  )
end
```

Comment: Hey., I tried your suggestion,but am getting `Return value is: nil` from the `bill_params` method.